# Issue with local/global scope and NAN

Tags: javascript, function, scope, nan, addeventlistener

Ok so I have the following code in order to create a calculator:

```
const numbers = document.querySelector('.numbers')
const display = document.querySelector('.display')
const functions = document.querySelector('.functions')
const equalClear = document.querySelector('.equalClear')

numbers.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // selecting and adding nr to display
   if(e.target.innerHTML == '1'){
       display.innerHTML += '1';
   }else if (e.target.innerHTML == '2'){
       display.innerHTML += '2';
   }else if (e.target.innerHTML == '3'){
    display.innerHTML += '3';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '4'){
    display.innerHTML += '4';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '5'){
    display.innerHTML += '5';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '6'){
    display.innerHTML += '6';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '7'){
    display.innerHTML += '7';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '8'){
    display.innerHTML += '8';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '9'){
    display.innerHTML += '9';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '0'){
    display.innerHTML += '0';
}
});

functions.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // selecting a function and adding it to the display
    if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Add'){
        display.innerHTML += '+';
        functionVal = add();
    } else if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Subtract'){
        display.innerHTML += '-';
        functionVal = subtract();
    } else if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Multiply'){
        display.innerHTML += '*';
        functionVal = multiply()
    } else if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Divide'){
        display.innerHTML += '/';
        functionVal = divide();
    }else{
        display.innerHTML + 'Error'
    }
    numberVal = display.innerText; //creating variable with value of nr in display
    console.log(numberVal, "numberVal");
    console.log(functionVal, "functionVal");
});

equalClear.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.innerHTML === 'Clear'){
        display.innerHTML = "";
    } 
    else if(e.target.innerHTML = '='){
    }
})

//functions for calculator

function add(variable1, variable2) {
    return variable1 + variable2;
};

function subtract(variable1, variable2) {
    return variable1 - variable2;
}

function multiply(variable1, variable2) {
    return variable1 * variable2;
};

function divide(variable1, variable2) {
    return variable1 / variable2;
}

// operation in calculator

function operate(operator, num1, num2){
   operate = operator, num1, num2;
}

operate(functionVal(numberVal,5))
console.log(operate, "this is an operation");
```

I define "functionVal" and "numberVal" within "functions.addEventListener". But when I try calling them within the "operate" function at the bottom of my code, I get that "functionVal" and "numberVal" is undefined. I know that this is due to it being in a local scope within the "functions.addEventListener" function, and I have tried adding a "var" for each of them before the code block in order to give them global scope. But it just won't work and I'm going a bit crazy trying to find out how to be able to call them within my "operate" function.

Also, when I call "functionVal" within "console.log" in the "functions.AddEventListener" I get that "functionVal" is NAN which I know is "not a number", but shouldn't it display the actual function that I gave it the value to have? I have set that if you press "add" in the HTML, the value of "functionVal" becomes the "add" function I have defined in the bottom of the code. I'm not sure what is going wrong here so any help would be very appreciated.

In the "operate" function, I have given the second parameter the value 5 just for testing, but will add the actual "second number" in the display once I have been able to sort out the issues.

Grateful for any assistance!

Kind regards,
A JS noob

Answer (score 0):

Okay, at first, this is really not good, why you sould ever check equality (and use `===` operator for the same types):

```
numbers.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // selecting and adding nr to display
   if(e.target.innerHTML == '1'){
       display.innerHTML += '1';
   }else if (e.target.innerHTML == '2'){
       display.innerHTML += '2';
   }else if (e.target.innerHTML == '3'){
    display.innerHTML += '3';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '4'){
    display.innerHTML += '4';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '5'){
    display.innerHTML += '5';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '6'){
    display.innerHTML += '6';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '7'){
    display.innerHTML += '7';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '8'){
    display.innerHTML += '8';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '9'){
    display.innerHTML += '9';
}else if (e.target.innerHTML == '0'){
    display.innerHTML += '0';
}
});
```

You can rewrite it like this:

```
numbers.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    display.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;
}
```

And if I understand correct, `numbers` must be array of buttons with numbers, but [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) return only first occurrence, so it will return only first button.
You should use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and rewrite it like this:

```
const numbersButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers');
// convert to array, because we can't iterate over querySelectorAll result
Array.from(numbersButtons).forEach((button,index) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
        display.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

Functions, probability, must be an array too, and you can make code clearer, using, for example map of functions:

```
const functionsMap = {
    '+': add,
    '-': subtract
    // and other functions..
}
```

And call them like this:

```
// will return add function
const targetFunc = functionsMap['+'];
// call with parameters
targetFunc(1,2);
```

And yes, when you make this:

```
 functionVal = divide();
```

You don't pass reference to function, you execute it, so `functionVal` will store result of function execute, and yes, it will return `NaN`, because you execute it with no params, try this in console:

```
function add (a,b){return a + b}
console.log(add());
```

There are still a lot of mistakes, which I will not analyze, so I advise you to go back to the very beginning and take good care of what you are doing.

Comment: Hi Rostegg, Thanks for your help!

I will go over the things you said and fix my code. 

Just one question. When I use "numbers.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    display.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;
)}"
and i click in between the numbers, my "display" gets the full "numbers <div>" added to it, wrapping it into a big circle underneath the acutal "numbers div". This is why I added the equality so it would exclude clicks outside the number buttons. Is there a way to exclude adding value to display from clicks outside the actual number buttons? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You need to find not parent element, but all buttons, here example: https://jsfiddle.net/p0xm469f/

Comment: Thanks for checking again, but the issue still remains, When I implement this into my js file and run it in my live server, when I press on a button the "alert" fires with the correct number being shown as a "popup" and it gets added to "display" (so far so good). But if I press in between the buttons, the alert shows "NAN" and then it wraps the display into a circle underneath the buttons for "numbers" rendering them unusable. So what I wonder is how I can solve that, I understand how to use the array etc, but the issue is that my "display" warps when using this, that is why I used equality.

Comment: Just provide link to your project (github or something else)

Comment: https://github.com/DojaCat/calculator.git Thanks so much again for checking this!

Comment: @DojaCat just create pr on github